# How can i pass form1 variables to user control class?

Tags: c#

I have this user control code the User Control is GraphChart:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace GatherLinks
{

    public partial class GraphChart : UserControl
    {
        Form1 form1;

        public GraphChart(Form1 f1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            form1 = f1;

        }

        private void GraphChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
            {
                Name = "Series1",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };

            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

            //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            //{
                series1.Points.AddXY(form1.axisX, form1.axisY);
            //}
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }
```

After adding form1 and f1 variables im getting error:

Error 2 GatherLinks.GraphChart' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

When I make double click on the error it's moving to Form1 designer cs to the line:

```
this.graphChart1 = new GatherLinks.GraphChart();
```

I tried to put Form1 in between the () but it's not working getting an error.
How can I solve it ?

EDIT:

I just did in the User Control code:

```
public partial class GraphChart : UserControl
    {
        Form1 form1;

        public GraphChart() { }
        public GraphChart(Form1 f1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            form1 = f1;

        }
```

But now in Form1 constructor I have this lines:

```
this.graphChart1.chart1.MouseMove += chart1_MouseMove;
this.graphChart1.chart1.MouseLeave += chart1_MouseLeave;
```

They worked before fine but as soon as I added the line: public GraphChart() { }
Im getting an error when running the application that chart1 is null .

Comment: Can you please show the not working syntax?

Comment: Fendy once I added form1 and f1 in the User Control code the error came up. There is no not working syntax. It's just it need me to pass Form1 to the GraphChart but I can't do it.

Comment: What is the Namespace you are using for your Form1

Comment: @user2065612 Then the not working syntax originally must be GraphChart graphChart1 = new GraphChart();

But that's ok. Now to working on your second problem, can you please give us the "caller" syntax?

Comment: @user2065612 What I mean by caller syntax is not just this.graphChart1.chart1.MouseMove += chart1_MouseMove; etc. Instead, please provide the initialization of this.graphChart1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that your `UserControl` has no idea what the `Form1` type is. You need to put a using statement at the top of your file to include your Forms Namespace, In my case I tested with `WindowsFormApplication1` though it will be what ever namespace that you used. And in your updated example you are never calling your `InitializeComponent` Method so you never create your Chart.

You can try something like this if you want to use a parameterless constructor: ( *note the addition of the InitializeComponent method to the Default Constructor and the addition of two additional methods `SetupGraph` and `SetForm` I also moved the code out of the `GraphChart_Load` eventhandler to the `SetupGraph` Method. This works both with passing Form1 in the Constructor and using the Parameterless Constructor as long as you use `SetForm` before you call `SetupGraph`*)

**UserControl**

```
public partial class GraphChart : UserControl
{
    private Chart chart1;
    Form1 form1;
    public GraphChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public GraphChart(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = f1;
        this.Load+=new EventHandler(GraphChart_Load);
    }
    public void SetForm( Form1 f1)
    {
        form1 = f1;
    }
    public void SetupGraph()
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = "Series1",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };

        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        //{
        series1.Points.AddXY(form1.axisX, form1.axisY);
        //}
        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
    private void GraphChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupGraph();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
        this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // chart1
        // 
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        legend1.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
        series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series1.Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.Name = "Series1";
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
        this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(519, 473);
        this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
        // 
        // GraphChart
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
        this.Name = "GraphChart";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int axisX = 100;
    public int axisY = 100;
    GatherLinks.GraphChart graphChart1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graphChart1 = new GatherLinks.GraphChart();
        this.Controls.Add(graphChart1);
        graphChart1.SetForm(this);
        graphChart1.SetupGraph();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a constructor that takes 0 arguments to the class, so try to add the following line to class GraphChart:

```
public GraphChart(){}
```

Comment: Terry I did it look at my question im updating it now this error is gone but im having another problem.